# Optics of stationary waves

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, optics, waves, water

could anybody tell me how it Works if it comes to stationary waves created on the surface of water jet and optics? there are some crests and troughs which work like lenses, but if you have water jet, how does it act like?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by water jet you mean a stream of water being propelled vertically, then it would act similarly in terms of shape of the waves. The water would follow the path of the wave, similarly to a pool of water. Imagine having a wide tube of the exact shape of your wave, then passing a stream of water through it. This water would fall through just as a regular stream, but once you introduced your wave, a molecule would follow the path of the wave and pass through the tube at the center of the tube the entire time. I will attempt to attach an illustration of these effects, but it may come in a later comment. There are YouTube videos that experiment the introduction of a wave to a stream of water,  such as this one here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mODqQvlrgIQ. (If this isn't a clickable link, simply copy and paste into a search engine). This experiment shows how a water stream, affected by waves of differing frequencies. These are vertical streams, but if you are wondering about horizontal streams (i.e. water gun) then the effects of the wave would be the same, but you would have to account for gravity. This would simply move the wave of water, most likely deforming it to the point of it being droplets of water, as water does, but the effects of the wave would still be visible if observed carefully. You can, from here, find out what it would look like from an optic standpoint. I hope this helps!